# How to give policy to other branch than default in azuredevops by terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, branch

I want to give policy to other branch than default one. For example azuredevops_branch_policy_status_check

I have this module:

```
resource "azuredevops_user_entitlement" "example-entitlement" {
  principal_name       = var.username
  account_license_type = "basic"
}

resource "azuredevops_branch_policy_status_check" "example-status-check" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id

  enabled  = true
  blocking = true

  settings {
    name                 = "Release"
    author_id            = azuredevops_user_entitlement.example-entitlement.id
    invalidate_on_update = true
    applicability        = "conditional"
    display_name         = "PreCheck"

    scope {
      repository_id  = azuredevops_git_repository.example-import.id
      repository_ref = azuredevops_git_repository.example-import.default_branch
      match_type     = "Exact"
    }

    scope {
      match_type     = "DefaultBranch"
    }
  }
}
```

and I wonder where should I put other branch so the policy would be applied to the one I want not the default branch (for example my other branch's name is test-branch)

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/branch_policy_status_check#scope

Comment: yes, I've been using this document but I don't know how to change it to other branch than default_branch

Comment: `repository_ref - (Optional) The ref pattern to use for the match when match_type other than DefaultBranch.`